# Nested extends in generics

Tags: java, generics

I have three classes:

```
class ClassR {}
class ClassA<T extends ClassR>{}    
class ClassB<E extends ClassA<T extends ClassR>> extends ClassA<T> {
    void foo(T param) {
    }

    void bar(E param) {
    }
}
```

The third class does not compile unless I change it to

```
class ClassB<E extends ClassA<T>, T extends ClassR> extends ClassA<T> {
    void foo(T bar) {
    }

    void bar(E param) {
    }
}
```

Is there a way to keep only E parameter I need to pass when creating ClassB, and T being inferred? For example, it would be convenient to use:

```
new ClassB<ClassA<ClassR>>()
```

instead of:

```
new ClassB<ClassA<ClassR>, ClassR>()
```

Comment: Side note: it's better to implement Runnable than to extend Thread.

Comment: changed to ClassR as it does not make a difference

Comment: please post method with usage of E

Comment: Are you doing anything with E?

Comment: Shot in the dark: does `class ClassB<E extends ClassA<T>> extends ClassA<T extends ClassR>` work?

Comment: IMHO the question is a bit confusing as the exact requirements are unclear. Do you really need 'E' and 'T' in class classB? Then it is impossible to omit one of these as there is no relationship in terms of inheritance, 'E' and 'T' could be independent types. Or do you mean something really different, more like 'E extends T'? Judging from the code I would say that there is some design flaw.

Answer (score 1):

This even simpler approach might work for you:

```
class ClassR {}
class ClassA<T extends ClassR>{}    

class ClassB<T extends ClassR> extends ClassA<T> {
    void foo(T bar) {
    }

    void bar(ClassA<T> param) {
    }
}
```

And usage then bypasses any reference to `ClassA` to become:

```
class SubR extends ClassR {}

ClassB<SubR> obj = new ClassB<SubR>();
```

Comment: I think this is a good answer. Judging from the shown code, 'E' is never returned from a method in ClassB. However in ClassB, (e.g. in method 'bar') you (the compiler) only know that it is something which can be seen as an ClassA<T>. Hence you can only invoke mthods from ClassA and T in a typesafe manner. Hence there is no need for the type parameter 'E'. However if there is code with a reference to an instance of ClassB which invokes methods of 'E' things are really different.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the answer you want but surely the simplest version reads:

```
class ClassR {
}

class ClassA<T extends ClassR> {
}

class ClassB<T extends ClassR> extends ClassA<T> {

    void foo(T bar) {
    }
}

public void test() {
    ClassB<ClassR> classB = new ClassB<>();
}
```

Comment: My bad, I use both E and T inside the ClassB, is there a way to still have E? (updated the question)

Answer (score 0):

As type `E` extends `ClassA` you can safely omit the `ClassA` type parameter in its declaration.
Proper `ClassA` type parameter is enforced in the second parameter to `ClassB`.
 See below code for illustration :

```
class ClassB<E extends ClassA, T extends ClassR> extends ClassA<T> {

  private ClassA ob;

  public ClassB(E e, T t)  {
    super(t);
    ob = e;
  }

}
```

Usage sample:

```
class ClassR { 
   public ClassR() {};
}

class ClassS extends ClassR {
  private int x;
  public ClassS(int x) {
     super();
     this.x = x;
  }
}

public static void test() {
  ClassS data1 = new ClassS(1);
  ClassB <ClassB, ClassS> first = new ClassB<>(null, data1);
  ClassS data2 = new ClassS(2);
  ClassB <ClassB, ClassS> second = new ClassB<>(first, data2);
}
```

Comment: With this solution you get ClassA as rawtype while inheriting from ClassA<T>. Whenever you need information about the generic type from ClassA in 'E extends ClassA' you are lost. As stated above I think that there is some design flaw which prevents us from providing a good implementation as the shown code smells like implicit requirements.